# preg replace for delet 0 in the first number until found 1-9

Tags: preg-replace

i have problem for this number 000000000480000.00

how to remove 000000000

to become 480000.00

i need in php and preg-replace function. Please help

thanks before

Answer (score 0):

try

```
preg_replace('(^0+)', '' , '000000000480000.00');
```